# Which spring-security version is compatible with Spring 4.3.10-RELEASE?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am upgrading JARs across the projects to the latest release/stable versions for live deployment. I did not have any issue upgrading until I tried upgrade :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

To:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I had to revert it back to 4.1.3 as I was getting :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
```

Has anyone tried it ?

Comment: The error you state is just a consequent of the actual error - find the root cause error message.

Comment: I am not sure if anyone has tried working with the latest release version for spring security bom and spring framework 4.3.10 release version. I have tried doing that and without making any code changes it's throwing me the exception mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes I will definitely try this and will revert back...thanks

Comment: I tried this one and it's still not working, appreciate your effort - Thanks :)

Comment: check `ApplicationContext.xml` is there multiple bean classes with the same name, check your classes once for ambiguity.